# showing "fecha invalida" in firefox but showing correct data in chrome

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, list, firefox

Below are the two images. One is from firefox and the other from google chrome. Inside end time there is "fecha invalida" in case of firefox but inside google chrome I am getting correct data inside of end time what I want.  start time and all other things are correct.  For showing lists of data I am using react-data-grid library in reactjs and php is my server. From server I am getting the exact data.

```
getTheDataGrid = (routeVal, serviceVal, versionVal) => {
    let routeId = routeVal;
    let serviceType = serviceVal;
    let versionId = versionVal;
    let customizedTimeIDA = [];
    let customizedTimeVUELTA = [];
    let idaStopsTravelTime = [];
    let vueltaStopsTravelTime = [];
    if (routeId != "" && serviceType != "" && versionId != "") {
      this.props.loadingStart();
      this.setState({
        rows: [],
        rowsCount: 0,
        rID: routeId,
        sType: serviceType,
        vID: versionId,
      });
      axios
        .get(`rutaRegular/createBlock/${routeId}/${serviceType}/${versionId}`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.Blocks[0].endTime, "res.dataaaaaa");
          let gridDataIndex = 1;
          let gridBlockId = "";

          if (res.data.Blocks && res.data.Blocks.length > 0) {
            res.data.Blocks.map((blockData, blockInd) => {
              if (gridBlockId == "" || gridBlockId == blockData.blockID) {
                blockData.blockIndex = gridDataIndex;
                gridBlockId = blockData.blockID;
              } else {
                gridDataIndex++;
                blockData.blockIndex = gridDataIndex;
                gridBlockId = "";
              }
            });
          }

          if (
            res.data.rutaTripStoppageTimesArr &&
            res.data.rutaTripStoppageTimesArr.length > 0
          ) {
            let tripGenerationParams = res.data.rutaTripStoppageTimesArr;
            let ida_stops_travel_times =
              tripGenerationParams[0]["ida_stops_travel_times"];
            let vuelta_stops_travel_times =
              tripGenerationParams[0]["vuelta_stops_travel_times"];

            ida_stops_travel_times.map((idavalue, idaindex) => {
              let customizedTimeIDAObj = {
                startTime: idavalue.startTime,
                endTime: idavalue.endTime,
                BlockInterval: idavalue.BlockInterval,
              };
              customizedTimeIDA.push(customizedTimeIDAObj);
              let idatravelTimeArr = [];
              idavalue.stopsTimes.map((idastvalue, idastindex) => {
                idatravelTimeArr.push(idastvalue.travelTime);
              });
              idaStopsTravelTime.push(idatravelTimeArr);
            });

            vuelta_stops_travel_times.map((vueltavalue, vueltaindex) => {
              let customizedTimeVUELTAObj = {
                startTime: vueltavalue.startTime,
                endTime: vueltavalue.endTime,
                BlockInterval: vueltavalue.BlockInterval,
              };
              customizedTimeVUELTA.push(customizedTimeVUELTAObj);

              let vueltaTravelTimeArr = [];
              vueltavalue.stopsTimes.map((stvalue, stindex) => {
                vueltaTravelTimeArr.push(stvalue.travelTime);
              });
              vueltaStopsTravelTime.push(vueltaTravelTimeArr);
            });
          }
          // console.log("customizedTimeIDA", customizedTimeIDA);
          // console.log("customizedTimeVUELTA", customizedTimeVUELTA);
          // console.log("idaStopsTravelTime", idaStopsTravelTime);
          // console.log("vueltaStopsTravelTime", vueltaStopsTravelTime);

          let gridData = res.data.Blocks;
          let blockIDChanged = 0;
          gridData.forEach((gridDataVal, idx) => {
            if (idx == 0) {
              gridData[idx]["changeColor"] = 0;
            } else if (
              idx > 0 &&
              gridData[idx]["blockID"] != gridData[Number(idx) - 1]["blockID"]
            ) {
              gridData[idx]["changeColor"] = 0;
              blockIDChanged++;
              if (blockIDChanged) {
                gridData[idx]["changeColor"] =
                  gridData[Number(idx) - 1]["changeColor"] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
              }
              blockIDChanged--;
            } else if (
              idx > 0 &&
              gridData[idx]["blockID"] == gridData[Number(idx) - 1]["blockID"]
            ) {
              gridData[idx]["changeColor"] =
                gridData[Number(idx) - 1]["changeColor"] == 1 ? 1 : 0;
            }
          });

          this.setState({
            rows: gridData,
            rowsCount: gridData.length,
            customizedTimeIDA: customizedTimeIDA,
            customizedTimeVUELTA: customizedTimeVUELTA,
            idaStopsTravelTime: idaStopsTravelTime,
            vueltaStopsTravelTime: vueltaStopsTravelTime,
          });


          this.props.loadingStop();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.setState({
            rows: [],
            rowsCount: 0,
          });
          swal("Error", err.data.message, "error");
          this.props.loadingStop();
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        rows: [],
        rowsCount: 0,
      });
    }
  };
```

```
                       <div className="parentOfDataGrid">
                          <ReactDataGrid
                            columns={cols}
                            rowGetter={(i) => this.state.rows[i]}
                            rowsCount={rowsCount}
                            rowRenderer={RowRenderer}
                            onGridRowsUpdated= {this.onGridRowsUpdated}
                            enableCellSelect={true}
                          />
                        </div>
```

```
const RowRenderer = ({ renderBaseRow, ...props }) => {
  const dynamicClass =
    props.row.changeColor == 0 ? "changeColorEven" : "changeColorOdd";
  return <div className={dynamicClass}>{renderBaseRow(props)}</div>;
};
```

```
onGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
    const re = /((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))/;
    let orginalRow = this.state.rows;
    let tempCustomizedTimeIDA = this.state.customizedTimeIDA;
    let tempCustomizedTimeVUELTA = this.state.customizedTimeVUELTA;
    let tempIDAStopsTravelTime = this.state.idaStopsTravelTime;
    let tempVUELTAStopsTravelTime = this.state.vueltaStopsTravelTime;
    let tempCustStTimeIDA = [];
    let tempCustStTimeVUELTA = [];

    let today = new Date();
    let dd = today.getDate();
    let mm = today.getMonth() + 1;

    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = "0" + mm;
    }

    let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    let startTimeInterval = 0;

    let tempPhrase = this.state.phrases ? this.state.phrases : [];

    tempCustomizedTimeIDA.forEach((value, idx) => {
      tempCustStTimeIDA[idx] = [
        moment(new Date(today + " " + value.startTime)),
        moment(new Date(today + " " + value.endTime)),
        value.BlockInterval,
      ];
    });
    tempCustomizedTimeVUELTA.forEach((value, idx) => {
      tempCustStTimeVUELTA[idx] = [
        moment(new Date(today + " " + value.startTime)),
        moment(new Date(today + " " + value.endTime)),
        value.BlockInterval,
      ];
    });

    this.setState({
      rearrangeFlag: 0,
    });

    this.setState(
      (state) => {
        const rows = state.rows.slice();
        console.log("fromRow", rows[fromRow].stTime);
        console.log("toRow", updated);
        for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
          rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...updated };
        }
        console.log("fromRow", rows[fromRow].stTime);

        for (let j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
          if (!re.test(rows[j].stTime)) {
            swal("Error", tempPhrase.InvalidTimeEntered, "error");
            return false;
          }
          if (typeof updated.blockID != "undefined") {
            if (orginalRow[j].blockID == orginalRow[fromRow].blockID) {
              rows[j].blockID = updated.blockID;
              rows[j] = { ...rows[j] };
            }
          }

          let prevCustIdx = 0;
          let changedCustIdx = 0;
          let updatedMoment = moment(new Date(today + " 00:00:00"));
          let originalStTime = moment(
            new Date(today + " " + orginalRow[j].StTime)
          );
          let totalIDARunTimeOnIdx = 0;
          let totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx = 0;

          if (orginalRow[j].stTime != rows[j].stTime) {
            updatedMoment = moment(new Date(today + " " + rows[j].stTime));
            if (rows[j].tripType == "IDA") {
              tempCustStTimeIDA.forEach((value, idx) => {
                if (
                  moment(originalStTime).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) ||
                  moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[0]) ||
                  moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[1])
                ) {
                  prevCustIdx = idx;
                }

                if (
                  moment(updatedMoment).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) ||
                  moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[0]) ||
                  moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[1])
                ) {
                  changedCustIdx = idx;
                }
              });

              tempIDAStopsTravelTime[changedCustIdx].map(
                (stopData, stopInd) => {
                  totalIDARunTimeOnIdx =
                    totalIDARunTimeOnIdx + Number(stopData);
                }
              );

              let endDateTime = new Date(today + " " + rows[j].stTime);

              endDateTime = moment(endDateTime)
                .add(totalIDARunTimeOnIdx, "minutes")
                .format("hh:mm A");

              rows[j].endTime = endDateTime;
              rows[j].totalRT = moment(new Date(today + " 00:00:00"))
                .add(totalIDARunTimeOnIdx, "minutes")
                .format("HH:mm");

              let updateTime = new Date(today + " " + updated.stTime);
              updateTime = moment(updateTime, "hh:mm A");
              // let previousSTime = moment(orginalRow[j].stTime, 'hh:mm A');
              // startTimeInterval = moment.duration(updateTime.diff(previousSTime));

              if (j + 1 < rows.length) {
                // console.log("endTime", endDateTime);
                // console.log("nextStartTime", rows[j + 1].stTime);
                let momentEndTime = moment(new Date(today + " " + endDateTime));
                let momentNextStartTime = moment(
                  new Date(today + " " + rows[j + 1].stTime)
                );
                if (moment(momentEndTime).isAfter(momentNextStartTime)) {
                  swal(
                    "Error",
                    "Change interferes with another start time",
                    "error"
                  );
                  return false;
                }
              }
              rows[j] = { ...rows[j] };
            } else {
              prevCustIdx = 0;
              changedCustIdx = 0;
              tempCustStTimeVUELTA.forEach((value, idx) => {
                if (
                  moment(originalStTime).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) ||
                  moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[0]) ||
                  moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[1])
                ) {
                  prevCustIdx = idx;
                }

                if (
                  moment(updatedMoment).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) ||
                  moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[0]) ||
                  moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[1])
                ) {
                  // console.log("Range", [value[0], value[1]]);
                  changedCustIdx = idx;
                }
              });

              tempVUELTAStopsTravelTime[changedCustIdx].map(
                (stopData, stopInd) => {
                  totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx =
                    totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx + Number(stopData);
                }
              );

              let endDateTime = new Date(today + " " + rows[j].stTime);
              // console.log("stTime", endDateTime);
              endDateTime = moment(endDateTime)
                .add(totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx, "minutes")
                .format("hh:mm A");
              // console.log("endDateTime", endDateTime);
              rows[j].endTime = endDateTime;
              rows[j].totalRT = moment(new Date(today + " 00:00:00"))
                .add(totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx, "minutes")
                .format("HH:mm");
              let updateTime = new Date(today + " " + updated.stTime);
              updateTime = moment(updateTime, "hh:mm A");
              // let previousSTime = moment(orginalRow[j].stTime, 'hh:mm A');
              // startTimeInterval = moment.duration(updateTime.diff(previousSTime));
              rows[j] = { ...rows[j] };
            }
          } //else{
          //   if(startTimeInterval != 0){
          //     console.log('J+'+j, startTimeInterval.asMinutes())
          //     let startTime = new Date(today+' '+rows[j].stTime);
          //     startTime = moment(startTime).add(startTimeInterval.asMinutes(),'minutes').format("hh:mm A");
          //     rows[j].stTime = startTime;
          //     let endDateTime = new Date(today+' '+startTime);

          //     // New Part
          //     updatedMoment = moment(new Date(today+' '+rows[j].stTime));
          //     if(rows[j].tripType == 'IDA'){
          //       tempCustStTimeIDA.forEach((value, idx) => {
          //         if(moment(originalStTime).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) || moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[0]) || moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[1])) {
          //           prevCustIdx = idx;
          //         }

          //         if(moment(updatedMoment).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) || moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[0]) || moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[1])) {
          //           changedCustIdx = idx;
          //         }

          //       });

          //       tempIDAStopsTravelTime[changedCustIdx].map( ( stopData, stopInd ) => {
          //         totalIDARunTimeOnIdx = totalIDARunTimeOnIdx + Number(stopData);
          //       } );

          //       let endDateTime = new Date(today+' '+rows[j].stTime);
          //       console.log('stTime', endDateTime)
          //       endDateTime = moment(endDateTime).add(totalIDARunTimeOnIdx,'minutes').format("hh:mm A");
          //       console.log('endDateTime', endDateTime)
          //       rows[j].endTime = endDateTime;
          //       rows[j].totalRT = moment(new Date(today+' 00:00:00')).add(totalIDARunTimeOnIdx, 'minutes').format("HH:mm");
          //       rows[j] = {...rows[j]};
          //     }else{
          //       tempCustStTimeVUELTA.forEach((value, idx) => {
          //         if(moment(originalStTime).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) || moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[0]) || moment(originalStTime).isSame(value[1])) {
          //           prevCustIdx = idx;
          //         }

          //         if(moment(updatedMoment).isBetween(value[0], value[1]) || moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[0]) || moment(updatedMoment).isSame(value[1])) {
          //           changedCustIdx = idx;
          //         }

          //       });

          //       tempVUELTAStopsTravelTime[changedCustIdx].map( ( stopData, stopInd ) => {
          //         totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx = totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx + Number(stopData);
          //       } );

          //       let endDateTime = new Date(today+' '+rows[j].stTime);
          //       console.log('stTime', endDateTime)
          //       endDateTime = moment(endDateTime).add(totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx,'minutes').format("hh:mm A");
          //       console.log('endDateTime', endDateTime)
          //       rows[j].endTime = endDateTime;
          //       rows[j].totalRT = moment(new Date(today+' 00:00:00')).add(totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx, 'minutes').format("HH:mm");
          //       rows[j] = {...rows[j]};
          //     }
          //     // New Part

          //     if(rows[j].tripType == 'IDA'){
          //       endDateTime = moment(endDateTime).add(totalIDARunTimeOnIdx,'minutes').format("hh:mm A");
          //     }else{
          //       endDateTime = moment(endDateTime).add(totalVUELTARunTimeOnIdx,'minutes').format("hh:mm A");
          //     }
          //     rows[j].endTime = endDateTime;
          //     rows[j] = {...rows[j]};
          //   }
          // }
        }

        let changeOfBlockID = 0;
        //let idx = 0;
        rows.forEach((rowsVal, idx) => {
          if (idx == 0) {
            rows[idx]["changeColor"] = 0;
          } else if (
            idx > 0 &&
            rows[idx]["blockID"] != rows[Number(idx) - 1]["blockID"]
          ) {
            rows[idx]["changeColor"] = 0;
            changeOfBlockID++;
            if (changeOfBlockID) {
              rows[idx]["changeColor"] =
                rows[Number(idx) - 1]["changeColor"] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
            }
            changeOfBlockID--;
          } else if (
            idx > 0 &&
            rows[idx]["blockID"] == rows[Number(idx) - 1]["blockID"]
          ) {
            rows[idx]["changeColor"] =
              rows[Number(idx) - 1]["changeColor"] == 1 ? 1 : 0;
          }
        });

        if (
          (fromRow == 0 && toRow == 0) ||
          rows[fromRow - 1]["blockID"] !== rows[fromRow]["blockID"]
        ) {
          let prevRowEndTime = moment(
            new Date(today + " " + rows[fromRow].endTime)
          );
          let currentStTime = moment(
            new Date(today + " " + rows[fromRow + 1].stTime)
          );

          let idleDuration = this.getIdleDuration(
            rows[fromRow]["routeType"],
            rows[fromRow]["totalRTmins"]
          );

          let diffOfDuration = moment
            .duration(currentStTime.diff(prevRowEndTime))
            .asMinutes();

          if (diffOfDuration < idleDuration) {
            swal(
              "Error",
              tempPhrase.LayOverTimeMustBeOfAtleast +
                " " +
                idleDuration +
                " " +
                tempPhrase.minutes,
              "error"
            );
            return false;
          } else {
            let midnight = moment(new Date(today + " " + "00:00:00"));
            rows[fromRow].layOver = moment(midnight)
              .add(diffOfDuration, "minutes")
              .format("HH:mm");

            return { rows };
          }
        } else {
          // let prevFromRow = fromRow - 1;
          // let prevToRow = toRow - 1;

          console.log("rows", rows);
          let tempRows = rows;
          let prevFromRowNew = fromRow - 1;
          let prevToRowNew = toRow - 1;
          let prevFromRow = fromRow;
          let prevToRow = toRow;
          let prevRowEndTime = moment(
            //new Date(today + " " + orginalRow[prevFromRow].endTime)
            new Date(today + " " + orginalRow[prevFromRowNew].endTime)
          );
          console.log("prevFromRowNew - ", prevFromRowNew);
          console.log("orginalRow - ", orginalRow[prevFromRowNew].endTime);
          console.log("@@@@@@@@@-----");
          console.log("fromRow", fromRow);
          console.log("toRow", toRow);
          console.log("fromRow", rows[fromRow]);

          let currentStTime = moment(
            new Date(today + " " + rows[fromRow].stTime)
          );

          let diffOfDuration = moment
            .duration(currentStTime.diff(prevRowEndTime))
            .asMinutes();

          let midnight = moment(new Date(today + " " + "00:00:00"));

          console.log("diffOfDuration", diffOfDuration);

          let idleDuration = this.getIdleDuration(
            orginalRow[prevFromRowNew]["routeType"],
            orginalRow[prevFromRowNew]["totalRTmins"]
          );

          if (diffOfDuration < idleDuration) {
            swal(
              "Error",
              tempPhrase.LayOverTimeMustBeOfAtleast +
                " " +
                idleDuration +
                " " +
                tempPhrase.minutes,
              "error"
            );
            return false;
          }
          // console.log(rows.length);
          if (
            rows.length > fromRow + 1 &&
            rows[fromRow + 1]["blockID"] == rows[fromRow]["blockID"]
          ) {
            let currentEndTime = moment(
              new Date(today + " " + rows[fromRow].endTime)
            );
            let nextStTime = moment(
              new Date(today + " " + rows[fromRow + 1].stTime)
            );
            let diffOfDurationNext = moment
              .duration(nextStTime.diff(currentEndTime))
              .asMinutes();
            let idleDurationNext = this.getIdleDuration(
              orginalRow[fromRow]["routeType"],
              orginalRow[fromRow]["totalRTmins"]
            );
            if (diffOfDurationNext < idleDurationNext) {
              swal(
                "Error",
                tempPhrase.LayOverTimeMustBeOfAtleast +
                  " " +
                  idleDurationNext +
                  " " +
                  tempPhrase.minutes,
                "error"
              );
              return false;
            }
            tempRows[prevFromRow].layOver = {
              layOver: moment(midnight)
                .add(diffOfDurationNext, "minutes")
                .format("HH:mm"),
            };
          }

          tempRows[prevFromRowNew].layOver = {
            layOver: moment(midnight)
              .add(diffOfDuration, "minutes")
              .format("HH:mm"),
          };

          // tempRows[prevFromRow].layOver = {
          //   layOver: orginalRow[prevFromRow].layOver,
          // };

          rows.slice();

          rows[prevFromRowNew] = {
            ...rows[prevFromRowNew],
            ...tempRows[prevFromRowNew].layOver,
          };
          rows[prevFromRow] = {
            ...rows[prevFromRow],
            ...tempRows[prevFromRow].layOver,
          };
          // for (let i = prevFromRowNew; i <= prevFromRowNew; i++) {
          //   rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...tempRows[prevFromRow].layOver };
          // }
          // for (let i = prevFromRow; i <= prevToRow; i++) {
          //   rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...tempRows[prevFromRow].layOver };
          // }

          return { rows };
        }
      },
      () => {}
    );
  };
```

using axios.get("API"), I am getting the all correct data like start time and end time as we can see in the image. To show grid data I am using react-data-grid. start time is correct in firebox and google chrome both but end time is only correct in google chrome not in firefox. For reference check images

Firefox image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzXWN.png)

Chrome image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWCW7.png)

Comment: Please, provide some code or better a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: clearly you are sending data which firefox cannot understand.  Since you don't show an example of the data, no one can help you.